# Tensorflow model fit() fails with CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM when using Conv3D and multi-GPU MirroredStrategy

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, multi-gpu

When executing a model fit that includes a `Conv3D` layer on multiple GPUs, I'm encountering a CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM error in the gradient computation step. No errors occur when running on a single GPU, nor when I swap out `Conv3D` with `AveragePooling3D` or `Conv2D`. However, `Conv3DTranspose` also fails.

```
  (0) UNKNOWN:  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3494): 'tensor' CUDNN_BACKEND_TENSOR_DESCRIPTOR: Check and Set the CUDNN_ATTR_TENSOR_DIMENSIONS Correctly
         [[{{node gradient_tape/replica_2/model/conv3d/Conv3D/Conv3DBackpropFilterV2}}]]
         [[update_3_3/AssignAddVariableOp/_91]]
         [[group_deps_1/_103]]
         [[div_no_nan/ReadVariableOp_4/_58]]
         [[group_deps_1/_95]]
```

With the `Graph execution error:` traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi_gpu_fail_repro.py", line 25, in <module>
    model.fit(x_data, y_data, batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=1)
  File "***/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "***/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 52, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/replica_2/model/conv3d/Conv3D/Conv3DBackpropFilterV2' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "***/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "***/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1054, in train_step
      self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "***/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 542, in minimize
      grads_and_vars = self.compute_gradients(loss, var_list, tape)
    File "***/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 275, in compute_gradients
      grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list)
Node: 'gradient_tape/replica_2/model/conv3d/Conv3D/Conv3DBackpropFilterV2'
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

input_shape = (28, 28, 28, 1)
num_samples = 10

x_data = tf.random.uniform((num_samples, *input_shape), 0, 1)
y_data = tf.random.uniform((num_samples, *input_shape), 0, 1)

multi_gpu=True # <== fails
#multi_gpu=False # <== works
devices = [] if multi_gpu else ['/gpu:0']

mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=devices)
print(f"{mirrored_strategy.num_replicas_in_sync} replica(s)")

with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    outputs = layers.Conv3D(1, 1)(inputs) # <== fails
    #outputs = layers.AveragePooling3D(1)(inputs) # <== works
    #outputs = layers.Conv2D(1, 1)(inputs) # <== works
    model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

model.fit(x_data, y_data, batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

I'm running this in a singularity container that's just the `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu` docker image

```
Python: 3.8.10

tf.version.VERSION: '2.12.0'

CUDA: V11.8.89

cuDNN: version 8600

GPUs:
device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB-LS, pci bus id: 0000:07:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
device: 1, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB-LS, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
device: 2, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB-LS, pci bus id: 0000:0b:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
device: 3, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB-LS, pci bus id: 0000:85:00.0, compute capability: 7.0
```

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: As per the associated github issue, this was due to setting the batch size incorrectly. Batch size must be a multiple of the number of GPUs run on. 

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/60935